# Get query results with a page title

Tags: wp-query, pages

I want access to an item details by `WP_Query` with page title

I tried this codes but failed:

```
<form method="GET" action="">
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="product">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="compare">
</form>
<?php  
if(isset($_GET['product']) && !empty($_GET['product'])) {

    $product_title = $_GET['product'];

    $prdocut_id = get_page_by_title($product_title);

    $args = array('page_id' => $product_id);
    $query = new WP_Query($args);

    if($query) :
        while ($query->have_posts()) :
            $query->the_post();
            the_title();
            the_content();
        endwhile;
    endif;
}
?>
```

Comment: Please explain how it fails. ps: you're missing a `<?php`.

Comment: sorry i didnt type <?php , now added . it just return hello world post id = 1 and that content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a problem with your  `get_page_by_title()` usage, since you assume it returns the *page ID*, but it returns an object/array or `null`. You also have to tell it about your custom post type.

I also assume your products are stored as custom post type *cars*.

Please try the following with a given product title (untested):

```
// DEBUG: Let's first try out an existing product title:
$product_title = 'Some product title'; #<-- Adjust this to your needs!

// User input:
// $product_title = filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'product', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );

// Search for pages with the above product title:
$product = get_page_by_title( $product_title, $output = OBJECT, $cpt = 'cars' );

// Product exists:
if( $product ) {
    $query = new WP_Query( array( 'p' => $product->ID ) );
    if( $query->have_posts() ) {
        while ($query->have_posts()) {
            $query->the_post();
            the_title();
            the_content();
        } 
    }
}
```

Hopefully this could be a starting point for some further debugging.

Comment: if custom post type is cars , i should change $cpt = 'cars' ? when i change it to cars it doesnt work

Comment: Yes, so you're using a custom post type and not pages?

Comment: yeah using post type

Comment: You should update your question with that extra information. I updated the answer.

Comment: you're welcome, best of luck with your project.